# Alternative solution for Android Emulator

Tags: android

Currently I am working with Android Studio. Emulator is slow while I am compiling 
my program. If any possible for reducing time execution or any other alternative solution for emulator please provide me.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install Intel HAXM...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433073/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the official Android simulator does not work well for you, maybe try the Genymotion one

https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Is Genymotion free?

Comment: @MohamedNasik as far as I know, it should be free for personal use